# AngularJS : continue execution in a controller once a looped service method has ended

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

I'm using a networkService in Angular which role is to loop while internet connection is off. The idea would be to go back and continue the execution as soon as connection is on again.

Here is a controller as an example

```
MyApp.controller('StartCtrl', function($scope, $cordovaNetwork, applicationService, networkService) {

  $scope.loading = { message: 'Loading application...' };

  // If we don't have an applicationId yet
  if (localStorage.getItem('applicationId') === null)
  {
    if ($cordovaNetwork.isOffline())
    {
      $scope.loading = { message: networkService.message };
      networkService.wait();
    }
    else
    {
      $scope.loading = { message: 'Connecting application...' };

      applicationService.add();
    }
  }

});
```

And here is the network service :

```
MyApp.service(
  "networkService",
  function($window, $cordovaNetwork)
  {
    var message = 'No internet connection';

    function wait()
    {
      if ($cordovaNetwork.isOffline())
      {
        $window.setTimeout(wait, 400);
      }
      else
      {
        message = 'Connected !';

        alert(message);
      }
    }

    // Returns public properties and methods
    return {
      message: message,
      wait:    wait
    };
  }
);
```

Here for example I would like to call `applicationService.add()` once the connection is back.

I have the feeling I have to use something like `.then()`, but I don't see how to use it with many "steps" like all the checkings you can have during an application loading and running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're also using AJAX calls you could use promises as all the AngularJS AJAX calls return a promise.

```
MyApp.service("networkService", function($q, $window, $cordovaNetwork){
   var message = 'No internet connection';
   var deferred = $q.defer();
   function wait(){
       if ($cordovaNetwork.isOffline()){
           $window.setTimeout(wait, 400);
       }else{
           message = 'Connected !';
           deferred.resolve(message);
       }
   }
   return deferred.promise;
});

// in your controller call: - this is then the same syntax to the AJAX calls in Angular.
networkService.then(function(result){ var message = result.data; });
```

As for your comment of Async functions you may want to look into using https://github.com/caolan/async which helps with tidying up nested function callbacks. There's really no way around nested callbacks in the situation you describe - technically Javascript is functional programming so it's all functions and callbacks, sometimes people don't use it that way though (me included).

Comment: Thanks ! This is closer to what I need :)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a callback function as parameter to the wait function will be like:

```
function wait(callbackFunc)
    {
      if ($cordovaNetwork.isOffline())
      {
        $window.setTimeout(wait, 400);
      }
      else
      {
       callbackFunc();
      }
    }
```

Now when you call wait you can pass it:

networkService.wait(applicationService.add);
//applicationService.add passed as paramter

So it will make use of closure and execute exactly like it is executing in the controller. This is a thing of beauty in JS:-)

Comment: Thank you very much, but the thing is : if I have to call a chain of functions once each one is executed, I'll have to write a lot of  overlapping like :

`networkService.wait(applicationService.add(
    function ()
    {
      if (condition) {
        networkService.wait(service2.method(
          function ()
          {
            // etc
          }
        );
      }
    );
));`

Is there a way to avoid that ?

Comment: Then you have to consider approach other than this. I thought you need to execute the funtion after success. Also if there are lot of overlapping functions, this is not the way to do.

Comment: Why do you want to do those overlapping functions?

Comment: For now that will do the trick ;) Because the idea is simply to check if the application is registered on the Rest server, then if the user is registered (and has a valid token), to load the application. I will optimize the API calls to get the maximum from each exchange. I'm just not sure about what will happen next when I'll have to check many data continuously once the application loaded.

Comment: I'll have a better example once I have written more code with all the AJAX calls, then I'll update the question.